# MYSQL Slow Query

Tags: mysql

How can I view mysql slow_query_log to see which query is taking too much time?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to [check if it's enabled](http://techchorus.net/enable-mysql-general-query-and-slow-query-log) in your MySQL configuration (mysql.ini or mysql.cnf, depending on your system):

```
# enable slow log:
slow_query_log = 1
# log queries longer than n seconds:
long_query_time = 5
# where to log:
slow_query_log_file = /path/to/your/logs/mysql-slow.log
```

Restart your MySQL server, then watch the logfile using whatever program you like - `tail` is the simplest:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/logs/mysql-slow.log
```

You may need to play a bit with the `long_query_time` setting to find the limit where the volume of logging isn't too low or too high, but *just right*.

Comment: my slow_query_log_file is "/var/log/mysql-slow-log".

Comment: @BhatiaVJ: That's possible, yes - that's why I added the instructions to get its location from config, as each distro may have the file in a slightly different location by default, plus the path is obviously configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of this log in my.ini file, and then open it in any text editor.

Answer (score 0):

if you ask google for "slow_query_log", [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) is the first hit - explaining all you need to know. you have to enable it, set a filename you like (if it's already set, you can find the configuration in you `my.ini`), start your queries and look ito that file...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running mysqld < 5.2, your my.cnf may look like

log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log //where to store log

long_query_time=3 //quickest query to log